# If condition at time not returning correct value

Tags: python, if-statement, indexing, odeint

I'm working in Python to answer this question about whether a group of aliens should bring a population of 5 million and a resource load of 1 million vs population of 1M and load of 5M... I'm trying to find out which of the 2 options would maximize the population on a new planet after after 200 years. Here is my code:

Here is my derivative function

```
def derivs3(y1, t):
    c = P0 + R0
    r = a / c
    q = (a + b) / c
    Pi = y1[0]
    Ri = y1[1]
    Wi = y1[2]
    # the model equations
    dPdt = q * Pi*Ri/(1+Wi)
    dRdt = - q * Pi*Ri/(1+Wi) + (a / q) * Wi / (t + .0001)
    dWdt = b
    return [dPdt, dRdt, dWdt]
```

Here, I define my parameters:

```
# model parameters
a = 0.02   # related to conversion of unallocated resources into population
b = 0.0001   # related to growth of knowledge
W0 = 0.0     # initial amount of knowledge

# time period
Tmax = 600 # years
```

Here is where I run odeint and plot my results:

```
# Put your code here
t  = np.arange(0, Tmax, 0.1)
P0 = 5
R0 = 1
y0 = [P0,R0,W0]
soln = odeint(derivs3, y0, t)
PSol = soln[:, 0]
RSol = soln[:, 1]
WSol = soln[:, 2]

P0 = 1
R0 = 5
y0 = [P0,R0,W0]
soln = odeint(derivs3, y0, t)
PSol2 = soln[:, 0]
RSol2 = soln[:, 1]
WSol2 = soln[:, 2]

plt.plot(t,PSol)
plt.plot(t,PSol2)
plt.legend(("5Bil Aliens, 1Bil Resources","1Bil Aliens, 5Bil Resources"), loc='upper left', prop={'size':15}, bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("time (years)")
plt.ylabel("Population (billions)")
plt.title("Populations vs. Time")
```

And here is where the issue is arising:

```
if PSol[200] > PSol2[200]:
    print("To maximize population after 200 years (for a total of", round(PSol[200],2),"billion aliens), the aliens should take a population of 5 Billion Aliens, and a load of 1 Billion Resources.")
elif PSol[200] < PSol2[200]:
    print("To maximize population after 200 years (for a total of", round(PSol2[200],2),"billion aliens), the aliens should take a population of 1 Billion Aliens, and a load of 5 Billion Resources.")
else:
    print("The population after 200 years will be the same (for a total of", round(PSol2[200],2),"billion aliens), whether the aliens take a population of 5 Billion Aliens and a load of 1 Billion Resources, or a population of 1 Billion Aliens and a load of 5 Billion Resources")
```

So it's returning the following print statements, which don't align with the graph that I'm getting. It's probably a problem with indexing, **but I'm using PSol[200] and PSol2[200] because I want to know how many aliens and resources they should bring if they want to maximize population after 200 years.** See below (ignore the line about 600 years, because I haven't adjusted them, knowing they'll return the same problems):

Here is the graph. I know it's right (asked help room), so it must be the indexed values that are off.

[image: Here is the graph]

Comment: @Norrius Sorry about that. Think I cleaned it up, and made sure it runs now (with the appropriate imports).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where `t` is defined in your code but the issue appears to be arising (as you suggest) from `t[200] != 200`.  This would be relatively easy to check by just adding a `print t[200]` line.

If this is indeed the case, you'll want to either determine the index for which `t==200` or interpolate.  I'd lean toward interpolating with [numpy.interp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) since this will allow you to investigate times that are not integer multiples of your timestep.

```
PSol_200 = np.interp(200, t, PSol)
PSol2_200 = np.interp(200, t, PSol2)
```

**Edit:**
With your recent edit, we can see that your timestep is 0.1 instead of 1 so `t==200` should occur at index 2000 instead of 200.  You were comparing populations after 20 years instead of 200.

Comment: Thanks so much for introducing me to interp, and also pointing out what I was doing wrong! Makes a lot of sense now.